# Installing wget on El Capitan

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to install wget (v1.17) on a recently updated MacMini now running 10.11.2 and get the following message when running ./configure:

```
[...]
configure: configuring for GNU Wget 1.17
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... build-aux/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/x/local/wget-1.17':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

Any ideas what is going on?

FYI

```
>: gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/5.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Configured with: ../gcc-5.2.0/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)
```

Comment: perhaps try using homebrew?

Comment: I'd like to understand what's going on.

Comment: check config.log file for clues?